# Django Createsuperuser Bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Is there some sort of bug when you use `createsuperuser` in Django?

I am literally typing the following: `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

Here is what happens:

1) The first time I type this, it will say

> Username (leave blank to use 'whatever')

: so I typed 'batman'

It then says

> 'batman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

When I retype `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it accepts my answer of batman.

I am on a Windows machine, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Instead of closing the pos and marking it as more details needed, why don't you tell me specifically what you need ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username batman
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use inverted comma(')
try this:

> `Username (leave blank to use 'whatever'):hello`